# How do I customise MS Word 'manage sources' (creating reference lists) to do what I want it to do?

Tags: citations, proofreading, copy-editing, cross-referencing

I am using the 'manage sources' facility in Microsoft Word to create a reference list/bibliography (Harvard) but am experiencing a number of problems such as:

1. I cannot include italics for species names
2. The automatic bibliography insertion will only include the first initial of each
   author (which is not always the one they are most commonly known by)
3. How do I get the bibliography to include the DOI? (and other fields
   of my choosing)
4. When inserting citations, Word includes the full list of corporate authors, which may sometimes be extremely long. How do I reduce this to 'XXX et al'?

Apologise that this seems like 4 different questions but I will be grateful for any pointers at all on how to use 'manage sources' more productively. I have googled this but the answers that come up only deal with basic stuff on how to insert a reference. I can't find anything that offers more detailed help.

Comment: Quite likely Word does not have those features. You could convert all references to plain text and then manually edit them. Or use a different reference manager.

Comment: Have you seen [this web page](https://libguides.reading.ac.uk/managing-references/word#:~:text=Word%20has%20its%20own%2C%20basic,add%20references%20to%20further%20documents.)?

Comment: Are you committed to MSWord? If so, then ignore this. If not, then maybe look at LaTeX.  https://www.latex-project.org/

Comment: This question would probably be better asked on another Stack Exchange site: https://superuser.com/

Comment: @BobaFit Unfortunately yes, but thanks anyway

Comment: @Nobody Thank you, it looks like it's only offering the basics again (which I already know) but useful for the pointers to other referencing systems

Comment: How about using something like [Zotero](https://www.zotero.org/support/word_processor_plugin_usage)? You can still edit the article in MS Word, but use something else for the bibliography like @Oliver882 and Nobody suggest.

Comment: @DavidS Thank you, I wasn't sure which SE to use but thought there might be other editors on here with the same problem. The name 'superuser' isn't very helpful when searching for the right site!